# Partial sum of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series

There is series as

```
X, (X+X/100), (X +(X + X/100)/100) ...
```

i.e each

```
new_element =  X +  0.01 * previous_element
```

What is the formula for a partial sum of, say, four elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be translated as the following recurrence relation:

$$a_{n+1}=X+\frac{a_n}{100}\space\space\space\space\text{where $a_{0}=0$}.$$
And we want to find $a_{n}$.

We have $$a_{n}=X+\frac{a_{n-1}}{100}$$
$$a_{n-1}=X+\frac{a_{n-2}}{100}$$
$$\cdot\cdot\cdot$$

So substituting the above gives

$$a_{n+1}=X+\frac{a_n}{100}=X+\frac{1}{100}(X+\frac{a_{n-1}}{100})$$
$$=X+\frac{X}{100}+\frac{1}{100^2}a^{n-1}=X+\frac{X}{100}+\frac{1}{100^2}(X+\frac{a_{n-2}}{100})$$
$$=X+\frac{X}{100}+\frac{X}{100^2}+\frac{1}{100^3}a_{n-2}=\cdot\cdot\cdot=X+\frac{X}{100}+...+\frac{X}{100^{k-1}}+\frac{1}{100^k}(X+\frac{a_{n-k}}{100})$$

Setting $k=n$ and using the geometric series formula (and that $a_{0}=0$) we obtain $$a_{n+1}=X+\frac{X}{100}+...+\frac{X}{100^{n-1}}+\frac{1}{100^n}(X+\frac{a_{0}}{100})$$
$$=X\big(1+\frac{1}{100}+...+\frac{1}{100^{n-1}}+\frac{1}{100^n}\big)$$
$$=X\sum_{k=0}^{n}(\frac{1}{100})^{k}$$
$$=X\frac{1-(\frac{1}{100})^{n+1}}{1-\frac{1}{100}}$$
$$=\frac{100}{99}X(1-(\frac{1}{100})^{n+1}).$$

Thus $$a_{n}=\frac{100}{99}X(1-\frac{1}{100^{n}})$$

So the partial sum for four elements would be $$a_{4}=\frac{100}{99}X(1-\frac{1}{100^4}).$$

---

If the above said $\color{red}{sequence}$ instead of $\color{blue}{series}$, then we would have $S_{4}=a_{1}+a_{2}+a_{3}+a_{4}$ for example. The sum of the first $n$ terms would be

$$S_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{n}$$
$$=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{100}{99}X(1-\frac{1}{100^k})$$
$$=\frac{100}{99}X\big[\sum_{k=1}^{n}1-\sum_{k=1}^{n}(\frac{1}{100^k})\big]$$
$$=\frac{100}{99}X\big[n-(\sum_{k=0}^{n}(\frac{1}{100^k})-1)\big]$$
$$=\frac{100}{99}X\big[n-(\frac{100}{99}(1-\frac{1}{100^{n+1}})-1)\big]$$
$$=\frac{100}{99}X\big[n-\frac{1}{99}(1-\frac{1}{100^n})].$$

Comment: Ares, I guess that a4 is just 4-th element, not sum of four elements. am i wrong?

Comment: Yes, you are wrong. From what you've written above, the $4$-th element is the sum of the first four terms. You can see from the recurrence relation that $a_{1}=X$, then $a_{2}=X+\frac{a_{1}}{100}=X(1+\frac{1}{100})=\frac{101}{100}X=\frac{100}{99}X(1-\frac{1}{100^2})$ is the sum of the first two elements, $a_{3}=X+\frac{a_{2}}{100}=X+\frac{1}{100}(X+\frac{X}{100})$ is the sum of the first three elements, etc.

Comment: $a_{n}$ gives the $n$-th partial sum, i.e the sum of the first $n$-terms. See [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+X%2B%28X%2B1%2F100%28X%2BX%2F100%29%291%2F100+%3D+100X%281-1%2F100%5E4%29%2F99) for the sum of the first four elements (the sum and the formula above agree).

Comment: ares, sorry . I meant that second element is (X+X/100) . So sum of first and second elements will be   : X  + (X+X/100)

Comment: Oh, in that case I think you meant to say "sequence" in the title. Please see what I've added to the answer above.

Comment: Thanks , Ares! Sorry , English isn't my native.

Comment: You're welcome! :-). I hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 0):

We can describe this as a sequence of functions
$$f_n(x) = \begin{cases} x & n=1 \\ x + \frac{1}{100}f_{n-1}(x)  & n >1 \end{cases} $$

One can prove via induction that
$$f_n(x) = \frac{100}{99} (1 - 10^{-2 n}) x. $$